# How do I handle the wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT event to sort a grid?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to sort a wxGrid. Now, [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html) tells me it doesn't support sorting, but that it does generate an event. This documentation tells me the event is called `wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT`. Fair enough!

Now, the problem is that I simply don't know how to get the event to work. I have an event table for my frame, which looks something like this:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MainWindow, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(XRCID("toevoegknop"), MainWindow::openAddWindow)
// A few other events that work
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

The events listed there already work perfectly fine. In my MainWindow class I declared a function:

```
void sortColumn(wxGridEvent& event);
```

Now, I want to add said `wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT` event. From my point of view the documentation isn't really super clear on what I should do, so I just tried adding the event by adding the following line to the event table.

```
wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT(MainWindow::sortColumn)
```

Brings up a syntax error, thus it isn't right. I noticed the other events just started with EVT, so I tried to remove the wx, but I'm still out of luck.

Searching the internet far and wide brought me to a [pastebin post](http://pastebin.com/mJz8gvzE) which handles the event by adding the following line to the constructor of the frame (in my case MainWindow)

```
Grid->Connect(wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Frame::OnGridColSort);
```

Which I adapted like this (the almost entire constructor for MainWindow)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, Collection* library, MovieDB* database)
: wxFrame(), library_(library), database_(database) {
wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame(this, NULL, _T("hoofdvenster"));

SetSize(size);
grid_ = (wxGrid *)FindWindowById(XRCID("filmtabel"));
// Irrelevant code removed, setting up the grid labels etc.

grid_->Connect(wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT,(wxObjectEventFunction)&MainWindow::sortColumn);
}
```

Which throws up an error:

> ‘wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT’ was not declared in this scope

So now I don't know what else I can try. Please do keep in mind that I only started messing about with wxWidgets a few days ago, so things that are trivial to any wxWidgets user might not be for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're using `wx 2.8.12` which does not implement `wxEVT_GRID_COL_SORT`. It was added in `wx 2.9` so you'd have to get the latest development release (`2.9.4`) to use it.

However, in `wx 2.8` you can handle `wxEVT_GRID_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK` and dispatch the event accordingly to emulate the event.

Either add the event to the event map,

```
EVT_GRID_CMD_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK(ID_GRID,Frame::OnGridLabelLeftClick)
```

or connect it in your constructor:

```
grid->Connect(wxEVT_GRID_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK,
    (wxObjectEventFunction)&Frame::OnGridLabelLeftClick);
```

```
void Frame::OnGridColSort(wxGridEvent& event) {}
void Frame::OnGridRowSort(wxGridEvent& event) {}

void Frame::OnGridLabelLeftClick(wxGridEvent& event) {
    // GetCol and GetRow will return the index of the col/row label clicked
    event.Skip(); // the next handler will select col/row/everything, based
                  // on the label clicked; remove to prevent selection
    if( event.GetCol() >= 0 )
        OnGridColSort(event);
    else if( event.GetRow() >= 0 )
        OnGridRowSort(event);
    else
        ; // if both are -1, the upper left corner was clicked (select all)
}
```

This will behave similarly to `EVT_GRID_COL_SORT`.